# Does an improper shutdown cause harm to the underlying OS or hardware?

Tags: windows-7, linux, fedora, operating-systems

Does sudden shut down due to power failure do any harm to the underlying OS or hardware ? My laptop's battery is dead, so sometimes due to power failure or due to some other reason there is an improper shutdown.

Does it cause any harm ?

Comment: besides filesystem corruption damage to the hardware is very unlikely.

Comment: @Ramhound Will you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

If the operating has data in memory that has not been written, including updates to the directory, then a power loss would mean loss of data or corruption of the directory data. If the shutdown was at the worst time possible, it would be during a write operation in which case more than one file may be damaged.

A long time ago I was running the SCO Xenix operating system and I  lost power during a storm. When the power came back the operating was so corrupted that I lost everything on the hard drive.

Regards
  Edawen

Answer (score 0):

Well, theoretically at least, the OS sends signals, to hard disk for instance, so that it shuts it down (stops spinning). That being done abruptly could have some side-effect, but I believe it's hard to determine, depending on how the hardware is designed.